# Comparing strings with tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know there is a way to check the value of the tensor, `tf.Session().run()`. I tried to compare the value of the tensor with the string, but it takes too long. Is there any other way?

```py
sess = tf.Session()
value = sess.run(output[0])  # type of output[0] : tensor

for i in range(len(image_list_LR)):
    if (image_list_LR[i] == value):  # type of image_list_LR[i] : string
        input_image_LR = image_list_LR_npy[i]
```

Comment: I'm guessing the inner line should be `input_image_LR[i] = image_list_LR_npy[i]`?

Comment: When `output[0]` and `image_list_LR[i]` are equal, I wanted to put `image_list_LR_npy[i]` in `input_image_LR`.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer so it should do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
image_list_LR = np.array(image_list_LR)
indices = np.where(image_list_LR == value) 
if indices:
    input_image_LR = image_list_LR_npy[indices[0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. It's a silly question, but could not compare string and tensor without `sess.run()`? It takes too much time to run.

Comment: @LUCY the tensorflow tensor does not have a value unless you run the session. So no its not possible unfortunately. Depending on what else you are doing in your code, you could do this at another time, but it is hard to say without seeing it.

Comment: @LUCY please accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: Thank you for your advice and detailed explanation!! Have a nice day!!:)

Comment: @LUCY Sure thing.